# Unable to get subdomain correct url when running locally

Tags: c#, angular, wildcard-subdomain

In the process of a building an Angular application, this application will have multiple subdomains so

client1.mysite.com
client2.mysite.com
client3.mysite.com

I have the following in my host file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1       client1.mysite.com
```

and I run the Angular app as so:

```
ng serve --host client1.mysite.com --port 4200 --open
```

which opens the url of

http://client1.mysite.com:4200/

When I try to grab the url within the Web API by doing:

```
var requestingUrl = HttpContext.Request.Host;
```

It gives me

```
localhost:4200
```

I was expecting to see client1.mysite.com, does anyone know why I can't get the client1.mysite.com in my web API

Comment: ng is an executable and you need to use the c# Process class to run the command line.

Comment: The initial host will be localhost:4200 because that's the destination of the request.  Your hosts file is redirecting the domain name. (DNS lookup by browser) Subsequent requests made via fetch, etc... will be where those are sent... (if localhost again, it's probably a different port)